# InotifyPropertyChanged : expression recursively calls the containing property

Tags: wpf, vb.net

On Set Property if certain condition match then i want to change the value of Set Property.

E.g. Item Gross Wt. = 5.55         Item Sales Rate = 2.892    Sales Value = 16.05 (Sales Value should rounded to 2 decimal) But actually (Sales Value / Gross Wt) <> 2.892. It should be 2.89189189 (Rate should be round upto 8 Decimal)

So whenever i enter rate 2.892 and it will set the Rate property and will set the Sales Value Property and again from there it will set the Rate Property.

By doing above property side there is no issue but my UI is not updating with 2.89189189 in Sales Rate TextBox.

See the code what i want to do this is not related to above example but having same issue.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class TextViewModel
   Implements INotifyPropertyChanged


Dim _View As MainWindow

Public Sub New(ByVal View As MainWindow)
    _View = View
End Sub


Private Property _MyValue As String
Public Property MyValue As String
    Get
        Return _MyValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _MyValue = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue")

        If value = "ABC" Then
            MyValue = "PQR"
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
   End Class
```

As described if i write ABC and tab then PQR should display in same textbox.

Is it possible?

Comment: You probably want to move `NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue")` down to just before `End Set` when define `MyValue` property.

Comment: This is just an example given above for understanding. My actual Problem i described with Item Example. Whenever I entered value of Item Rate, First it will NotifyProperty of ItemRate, from same property i will calculate ItemValue and hence ItemValue Property will notify. Now ItemValue have only two decimal hence i want to update ItemRate again  . So again i change ItemRate Property inside ItemValue Property.

Comment: You were asking *As described if i write ABC and tab then PQR should display in same textbox. Is it possible?*. My comment above exactly tells you why your simple code was not working and how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You are Notifying of the property change too early. You first notify that it has changed, then change it. You should change it, then notify. Hope that helps!

My comment was too long so I'm adding it here: I think I understand what you are saying; in your CODE EXAMPLE, you are recursively calling the setter from the setter. But in your WRITTEN COMMENT, you are setting the properties back and forth (likely an infinite loop). THESE ARE TWO DIFFERENT PROBLEMS. In your CODE EXAMPLE, if you move the NotifyPropertyChanged event to the very end of the setter, it will work as you want. It will NotifyPropertyChanged TWICE though AFTER everything has changed (once for the "child" setter call and once for the "parent" setter call). In your WRITTEN example, first, update _ItemRate, then set ItemValue. Within ItemValue, update _ItemValue, then update _ItemRate (NOT ItemRate), and NotifyPropertyChanged for both ItemValue AND ItemRate WITHIN THE SETTER OF ItemValue. This will get you out of your infinite loop.

Comment: ...And only Notify if the value is different.

Comment: This is just an example given above for understanding. My actual Problem i described with Item Example. Whenever I entered value of Item Rate, First it will NotifyProperty of ItemRate, from same property i will calculate ItemValue and hence ItemValue Property will notify. Now ItemValue have only two decimal hence i want to update ItemRate again  . So again i change ItemRate Property inside ItemValue Property.

Answer (score 0):

But there is no need to call the Set recursively
Extra calls to NotifyPropertyChanged is just extra traffic

```
Set(value As String)
   If _MyValue = value then
       return
   End If
   _MyValue = value
   If _MyValue = "ABC" Then
       _MyValue = "PQR"  
   End If
   NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue")
End Set
```

Comment: This is just an example given above for understanding. My actual Problem i described with Item Example. Whenever I entered value of Item Rate, First it will NotifyProperty of ItemRate, from same property i will calculate ItemValue and hence ItemValue Property will notify. Now ItemValue have only two decimal hence i want to update ItemRate again  . So again i change ItemRate Property inside ItemValue Property.

Comment: You said that had the same issue.  Did it fix the issue or not?